# How to do a Search in EndlessRecycer view, changing endpoint of data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-search

I'm trying to do and app that brings data from an API in a EndlessRecyclerView.

At is moment, I'm able to call the API, bring the data (movies in my case) in a endlessrecyclerview. But, I want to implement the search, calling another URL from the api, and again in a "endless mode".

Right now I have:

```
oncreate(){
....
mMovieList = new ArrayList<>();
        mMovieAdapterRecyclerView = new MovieAdapterRecyclerView(this, mMovieList);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapterRecyclerView);
        receiveMovies(0);

        scrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerViewListener((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
                receiveMovies(page);
            }
        };
        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
    }
```

How I get the data:

```
private void receiveMovies(int pages) {
        final int mPages = pages;

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                    MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

                    //https://api.trakt.tv/movies/popular?page=2&limit=10
                    String mUrl2 = ConnectionUtils.TRAKT_URL + ConnectionUtils.POPULAR
                            + ConnectionUtils.TRAKT_PAGE + mPages + ConnectionUtils.TRAKT_LIMIT + PAGE_LIMIT
                            + "&" + ConnectionUtils.ALL_INFO;

                    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                            .url(mUrl2)
                            .addHeader(ConnectionUtils.TRAKT_API_VERSION, ConnectionUtils.TRAKT_API_VERSION_NUM)
                            .addHeader(ConnectionUtils.TRAKT_API_KEY, ConnectionUtils.API_KEY)
                            .addHeader(ConnectionUtils.TRAKT_CONTENT, JSON.toString())
                            .get()
                            .build();

                    Response clientResponse = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    String responseJson = clientResponse.body().string();
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Movie>>() {
                    }.getType();
                    ArrayList<Movie> movieaux = gson.fromJson(responseJson, listType);
                    mMovieList.addAll(movieaux);
                    return true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
                if (aBoolean) {
                    Logger.d(mMovieList);
                    mMovieAdapterRecyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    Logger.e("not loaded");
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

My problem is how can I "change" the actual data, to the search results, and when query is empty, go back again to the "general" data.

P.D: I take as example of EndlessRecycles from : https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView

Comment: Maintain two separate lists one for original data and another for search results. Swap them out based on user interaction i.e searchview is opened or closed.

Comment: But, if I swap list, every time I scroll down, endless scroll will load the movies without search filter.

Comment: Just enforce a check, if user is searching then don't execute the endless scroll load more operation.

Comment: @blizzard at the end I did something like you told. I checked with a flag, if users was searching or not, and show one list or other.